# How to control the color of a UIWebView (before contents load)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiwebview

I am trying to have a BLACK colored UIWebView before its contents load. In IB, i tried both making the background color of the UIWebView black, as well as, making it have a transparent background and have its parent view's background be black. Both don't work. When my UIWebView loads the background of it is white. How can I fix this?

***I hope this does not boil down to having to load an html string first (before loading my actual web content) to set the background to black vis CSS.**

Comment: I found the perfect solution!! http://stackoverflow.com/a/3316909/456536

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually setting the background color cannot make the web view entire black. The content of a web page is presented in a subview within the web view, a web view contains many undocumented subviews, including a UIScrollView which allows you to scroll the contents, and a UIScrollView contains UIWebDocumentView, which draws the web contents. They are above the background of your web view, so they cover the background, what you can see is the UIWebDocumentView and setting the background color cannot make your web view entire black.

I guess the solution is, you may try to place a black view over your web view, and hide the view when the delegate methods such as `webViewDidFinishLoad:` or `webViewDidStartLoad:` are called.

Comment: The less memory prone solution would be to hide/show the webview itself on viewwillappear or didstartload/didfinishload (that's actually the way i do it).

Comment: [webView setOpaque:NO];

Answer (score 24):

The way I did this was to put the UIWebView on a black colored view.  Then, we set the web page and the webview to be clear.  Works in iOS 4.2 .

On the superview:

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

On the webView:

```
webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

In the Web HTML:

```
<body style="background-color:transparent;">
```

Comment: webView.opaque = NO;
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; worked for me! thanks

Comment: I can confirm this is still working on iOS 6.1 and a certain newer version of iOS :)

Answer (score 11):

Actually, this is really simple:

```
[self.webView setOpaque:NO];
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```

This will show the background color, and as soon as the webview loads it will, happily, disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Try This it work for me,

Follow below steps ,

**Set UIview and webview opaque = NO and background Color is white**

[image]

Add below line of code before load of web view,

```
  _webViewOutlet.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1];
```

Hope so this is help for someone

Answer (score 1):

to remove this white flicker I only change backgroundColor to the color of my view. my code uses purple to show more general example. black is used simply as `UIColor.black`

editing `loadView` is not working for me, but `viewWillAppear` worked fine

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    ...
    webView.isOpaque = false
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 41/255, green: 45/255, blue: 91/255, alpha: 1)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7, here's another example.  "Self" is a UIViewController that's been pushed onto the Navigation Controller stack:

```
- (void) loadView
{
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];      // iOS 7 - make the web view the entire display

// -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491654/how-to-control-the-color-of-a-uiwebview-before-contents-load --

    webView.backgroundColor = [[Settings sharedInstance] backgroundColor];
    webView.opaque          = NO;                                               // setting this to NO fixes the background color problem
    webView.delegate        = self;

    self.view = webView;

    NSBundle      *thisBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString            *path = [thisBundle pathForResource: @"Instructions" ofType: @"html"];
       NSURL *instructionsURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: path];

    [webView loadRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: instructionsURL]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an UIView (I used blackView) with your custom color background (I used black color) over the WebView, and then show it on load WebView and hide when loaded. 
WebView must have background transparent and the root view must have the same background color of your custom color (black in my case)

- in **viewDidLoad**()
  `view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  webView.opaque = false`
- in **webViewDidStartLoad**(webView: UIWebView)
  `blackView.alpha = 1`
- in **webViewDidFinishLoad**(webView: UIWebView) 
  `blackView.alpha = 0`